# eBay managing listings via API

Tags: php, ebay-api

Using PHP5, how can I use the eBay API to set all my 2000+ eBay Store items on sale except for a specific set of 45 items?

I can't find a way to do this on eBay's website, and would prefer an API method so that I can simply exclude a specific brand from my query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like I found the answer:

1. [SetPromotionalSale](http://developer.ebay.com/DevZone/XML/docs/Reference/eBay/SetPromotionalSale.html)
2. [SetPromotionalSaleListings](http://developer.ebay.com/DevZone/XML/docs/Reference/eBay/SetPromotionalSaleListings.html)